# What are the steps to follow to make a query and use it on a ListPage Form?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

Could someone tell me the steps to complete to have a query and use it at a ListPage.

The development takes place in Microsoft Dynamics AX.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc616937.aspx). When you are ready, you will find lot of list pages in the applications.